# If condition in cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Can you pleas advice if the below IF condition in CF is correct.
It is to send the call the SNS topic, if the condition is true then send message to mentioned 3 arn.But I see that he If condition is not correct while using array

```
SnsTopicArns:
    !If [firstvalue,
      - '{{resolve:ssm:/monitoring/configurationar11:1}}'
      - '{{resolve:ssm:/monitoring/configurationarn2:1}}'
      - '{{resolve:ssm:/monitoring/configurationarn3:1}}',
      - !ImportValue someotheralarm]
```

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that you have bunch of questions with answers, but not a single one was accepted. It is a good practice to accept questions which were helpful as it also can help others in future and signals to people who answer that a given issues was solved.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, your logic is:

- if `firstvalue` is true, then send to the 3 ARNs
- if `firstvalue` is false, then use the `!ImportValue`

If this is correct, then you will need to use a mix of [`AWS::NoValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html) and your functions, since the "If" is not a block in CloudFormation. It is a function that needs to be applied to each value on the array you are providing. The `AWS::NoValue` is a way of telling AWS that you actually don't want a value present there: if this gets use in a property, it behaves as if the property was not set; if it is used in an array item, it behaves as if the item didn't exist.

I'd suggest you try this:

```
SnsTopicArns:
  - !If [ firstvalue, '{{resolve:ssm:/monitoring/configurationarn1:1}}', !Ref AWS::NoValue ]
  - !If [ firstvalue, '{{resolve:ssm:/monitoring/configurationarn2:1}}', !Ref AWS::NoValue ]
  - !If [ firstvalue, '{{resolve:ssm:/monitoring/configurationarn3:1}}', !Ref AWS::NoValue ]
  - !If [ !Not [ firstvalue ], !ImportValue someotheralarm, !Ref AWS::NoValue ]
```

**UPDATE**:
I was doing some testing and I believe this works too:

```
SnsTopicArns:
  Fn::If:
    - firstvalue
    - - '{{resolve:ssm:/monitoring/configurationarn1:1}}'
      - '{{resolve:ssm:/monitoring/configurationarn2:1}}'
      - '{{resolve:ssm:/monitoring/configurationarn3:1}}'
    - - !ImportValue someotheralarm
```

Comment: Hey Tyron, I get this error for Not condition
`Template error: Fn::Not requires a list argument with one function token`

Comment: @wasimmir did you add the `[` and `]` around firstvalue? Any chance you can provide your current template, removing any confidential information?

Comment: @wasimmir did this answer (or any other) solve your problem? If so, please accept the answer.

Comment: The second of the code snippets (UPDATE) worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, its not correct as the syntax is:

```
!If [condition_name, value_if_true, value_if_false]
```

Therefore, you can try the following:

```
SnsTopicArns:
    !If
      - firstvalue,
      - - '{{resolve:ssm:/monitoring/configurationar11:1}}'
        - '{{resolve:ssm:/monitoring/configurationarn2:1}}'
        - '{{resolve:ssm:/monitoring/configurationarn3:1}}'
      - !ImportValue someotheralarm
```

Note, the your template can still fail, depending on what is `someotheralarm` and the remaining context of your template which is not shown in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I will check and let you know

Comment: is there space between two dashs that refer to array ?
-- or - -

Comment: I got below error when executing the stack

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template error: unresolved condition dependency firstvalue, in Fn::If

Comment: @wasimmir I don't know what is `firstvalue`. Its not shown in your question. I wrote in the answer that there is no context provided for this if statement in your question.

Comment: first values is a defined condition which check for region and if the region is true then it should send to 3 arn and if false then use !ImportValue. (Import value is also an arn )